# jQuery append wrong position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to order elements from one list into two lists. However, when I drop the element and append it to the target div, the position is very strange (almost random).

```
<div class='container'>// contains generated words, draggable
  <div class='word'>Word</div>
  <div class='word'>Word 2</div>
  ...
</div> 
<div class='target' id='target1'></div> // made droppable
<div class='target' id='target2'></div> // made droppable
```

The drop function:

```
$('.target').droppable({drop: function(e,ui) {
  $(this).append(ui.draggable);
}});
```

The following fiddle shows the problem with one target.

http://jsfiddle.net/YZ8vJ/12/

I'm clueless why this is happening, and I haven't found an answer on SO or on the internet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the position elements are append depends on the position you drop them. I add a div in your html `<div id="dropEleme"></div>` so the drop elements append there. Also i change a bit your js code to reset style:

**js**

```
var a = ["word", "word2", "word3"];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    $('.words').append(makeDiv(a[i]));
}
function makeDiv(e) {
    return "<div class='word'>" + e + "</div>";
}
$('.word').draggable({revert:'invalid'});
$('.target').droppable({drop:function(e,ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).attr("style",""); //added this line to reset style, like position.
    $("#dropEleme").append(ui.draggable);
}});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ8vJ/22/)

Answer (score 1):

using

```
$(this).append(ui);
```

instead of

```
$(this).append(ui.draggable);
```

fixes the problem..here's the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ8vJ/24/)

Comment: sorry for that..i just looked for the desired effect on UI..didn't check the DOM..ignore the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css class for `.word`:

```
.word {
    background-color: coral;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 10px;
}
```